# How to programmatically insert and update Field Collection values?

Tags: 8, entities

I would like to insert and update [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) values. I'm using Drupal 8 with `field_collection 8.x-1.0-alpha1`.

## Setup

I have created a new content type `test_content_type` with the following fields:

- Title
- Body
- …
- Test Field Collection

  - Machine name: `field_test_field_collection`
  - Type: `field collection`

The field collection `field_test_field_collection` has only one field:

- Example Text

  - Machine name: `field_text`
  - Type: `text`

## The Problem

I also created a node with values, for instance `Lorem Ipsum` as `field_text.value`, but I don't know how to read and define the value programmatically. I tried the following, which updates `body` but doesn't update `field_text`:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface;

class FieldCollectionTestController extends ControllerBase {
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function content() {
        $nodeId = 1402;

        /** @var EntityStorageInterface $entityStorage */
        $entityStorage = Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
        $node = $entityStorage->load($nodeId);

        // Dump.
        {
            ob_start();
            var_dump($node->field_test_field_collection->field_text);
            $dump = ob_get_clean();
        }

        // Update node and field collection.
        {
            $exampleText = "Updated at " . time();

            $node->body = $exampleText;
            $node->field_test_field_collection->field_text = $exampleText;

            $node->save();
        }

        $response = [
            '#theme' => 'item_list',
            '#title' => 'Dumps',
            '#items' => [
                [
                    '#type' => 'markup',
                    '#markup' => $dump,
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return $response;
    }
}
```

The value of `$dump` is `null`.

## Question

How do you insert, update and delete Field Collections in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following snippet (compatible with `field_collection 8.x-1.0-alpha1`) reuses an existing `FieldCollectionItem` or creates a new one on demand. The last few lines show how to modify fields inside the `FieldCollectionItem`.

If one has a field collection with a different name, then it should be enough to replace all occurrences of `field_test_field_collection` with the custom field collection's machine name.

```
<?php

// […]

$nodeId = 123;

/** @var EntityStorageInterface $entityStorage */
$entityStorage = Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');

$node = $entityStorage->load($nodeId);
$node->body = 'Body Update: ' . date('c');

/** @var Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList $fieldItemList */
$fieldItemList = $node->field_test_field_collection;

// Reuse existing Field Collection.
if (count($fieldItemList))
{
    /** @var \Drupal\field_collection\Plugin\Field\FieldType\FieldCollection $fieldCollection */
    $fieldCollection = $fieldItemList[0];
    $fieldCollectionItem = FieldCollectionItem::load($fieldCollection->value);
}

// Create new Field Collection.
else
{
    $fieldCollectionItem = FieldCollectionItem::create([
        'field_name' => 'field_test_field_collection',
    ]);

    $fieldCollectionItem->setHostEntity($node);

    $node->field_test_field_collection[] = [
        'field_collection_item' => $fieldCollectionItem,
    ];
}

$fieldCollectionItem->set('field_text', 'Last Update: ' . date('c'));

$node->save();
```

Deleting an existing collection is as simple as: `fieldCollectionItem->delete();`

Please have a look at the source code of the unit test class `Drupal\field_collection\Tests\FieldCollectionBasicTestCase` for more information.

Answer (score -2):

Check the below link,

https://www.drupal.org/node/2683787

That may help you in your case.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Unfortunately, it didn't help me to find the answer. The snippet of drupal.org user smaz doesn't save the collections on my system.