# Programmatically creating a new instance of a custom content entity that contains a field collection

Tags: 8, entities

I am trying to write a script that will create about a thousand instances of a custom content entity type I defined via a module from existing data that I have prepared. Right now I just need to figure out how to create an instance of my entity type programmatically.

This entity type contains multiple field collections. I don't understand how to structure the arguments of {entity_type}::create() to accommodate field collections.

Following the accepted answers to [Programmatically create nodes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185442/programmatically-create-nodes) and [How to programmatically insert and update Field Collection values?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205624/how-to-programmatically-insert-and-update-field-collection-values), here is my function code so far (i have it inside `hook_entity_view_alter()` just for easy testing):

```
$food = Food::create([
    'type'  => 'food',
    'title' => 'Allspice',
    'field_category' => 'Spices'
]);
$variation = FieldCollectionItem::create([
    'field_ingredients' => 'allspice',
    'field_safe_for' => [
        'field_nut_allergies' => 'Yes',
        'field_seafood_allergies' => 'Yes',
    ]
]);
$variation->setHostEntity($food);
$food->field_variations[] = ['field_collection_item' => $variation];
$food->save();
```

where `food` is my entity type, `field_variations` is the ID of the field collection in `food` which may have unlimited values per `food` instance, and `field_safe_for` is a nested field collection.

No matter what I do, I always get this:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: Missing bundle for entity type field_collection_item in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->doCreate() (line 83 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase.php).
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->create(Array) (Line: 509)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity::create(Array) (Line: 39)
food_food_view_alter(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 501)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->alter(Array, Array, Object, Object) (Line: 268)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder->buildMultiple(Array) (Line: 203)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder->build(Array)
call_user_func(Array, Array) (Line: 381)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 195)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, ) (Line: 226)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}() (Line: 574)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 227)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 117)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object) (Line: 144)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 62)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 98)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 77)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 628)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

which I do not understand in the slightest since my custom entity types don't make use of bundles.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bundle of the entity type "field_collection_item" is `field_name` and the error messages says this is missing:

```
$variation = FieldCollectionItem::create([
  'field_name' => 'my_field_name',
  ...
```